# Maven: Forking a multi-module project and setting a custom label

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Fighting with Maven while forking modules from an open source project. The source is a multi-module Maven project with this structure:

```
.
 |-- module-a
 |   `-- pom.xml
 |-- module-b
 |   `-- pom.xml
 |-- module-c
 |   `-- pom.xml
 |-- module-...
 |   `-- pom.xml
 `-- parent
     `-- pom.xml
```

Forking the entire project is not an option. I only need to fork a few modules, e.g. `module-a` and `module-b`.

Versioning should track the original numbers, appending a suffix at the end: `-${org}-${inc}`, where:

- `${org}` is the organisation's name (fixed)
- `${inc}` is an ordinal that we'll increment every time we release the project forked from the same community version.

I preserve the link back to the original project by keeping the parent reference. So my fork inherits from the community's parent POM.

The problem arises because the community parent POM declares inner dependencies to be shared by all children artifacts using `<version>${project.version}</version>`.

Therefore, setting my fork versions to something like: `3.10.1-org-01` doesn't work, because the build expects other related artifacts which I don't require forking to be present with version `3.10.1-org-01`.

Setting the `finalName` to something like `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${org}-${inc}` doesn't help either, because even though the artifact appears with the right name in the build output directory (target/), it still gets installed to the Maven repo with the old name, thus overriding the community version and creating an untruthful reality.

I haven't found a way to make classifiers my friend in this case, either.

Any ideas apart from forking also the community parent POM and tailoring the dependency version numbers of the forked modules?

Thanks!

Comment: The simple solution is to fork the whole project and that's the way you have to go.

Comment: @khmarbaise As I expressly mentioned above, forking the entire project is not an option. In fact, this is an extremely modular project with 100+ modules where I only need to modify 2, so forking the entire codebase is overkill. You make it sound like there's only one solution to this problem, but there are many. As a matter of fact, I managed to solve it by forking the parent POM too. Clean, simple and lightweight.